# Multiple Templates not loading

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am having an issue loading multiple templates, and trying to follow this guide, https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/working-with-multiple-templates-1

In my app/src I have...
Homepage.php

```
<?php

namespace SilverStripe\Home;

use Page;    

class HomePage extends Page 
{

}

?>
```

HomepageController.php

```
<?php

namespace SilverStripe\Home;

use PageController;    

class HomePageController extends PageController 
{

}

?>
```

In my /custom_theme/templates I have

```
<html>
<head>
    ..
</head>

<body>
    <% include Header %>
    <% include Navigation %>

    $Layout

    <% include Footer %>
</body>
```

and in my /custom_theme/templates/SilverStripe/Home/Layout/HomePage.ss I have the html markup.  Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong here?, as I am able to choose the Home Page as a **page type** in the CMS backend, but the page does not load a template at all, simply outputs the content from the CMS.

I have also tried creating a new page template that is not namespaced and based off of the default Page.php and PageController.php code which also  **does not** load.  However, the default Page.ss template **does** load.

theme.yml

```
---
Name: mytheme
---
SilverStripe\View\SSViewer:
  themes:
    - 'bdsteps'
    - '$public'
    - '$default'
SilverStripe\i18n\i18n:
default_locale: 'en_US'
```

bdsteps = custom_theme

Comment: Sanity checks: the template name matches your PHP class name (plus Layout added), you have flushed, your `custom_theme` is enabled via configuration

Comment: I've checked that the name matches the class, and flushed.  I just added a bit more info to my question.

Comment: Can you please check that you've got the theme enabled?

Comment: The theme is set in the app/_config/theme.yml file

Comment: Is custom_theme inside the themes directory?

Comment: Yes, the custom_theme is located in the themes directory.

Comment: Can you share your theme.yml?

Comment: I just updated the question with the theme.yml

Comment: You don’t have custom_theme in it. Also make sure you indent your YAML correctly- the dash lines should be four spaces

Comment: bdsteps is my custom_theme, I used that as a reference.  The YAML is properly indented in the project.

Comment: Can you please post a realistic example of your code?

Comment: Somehow I got this working correctly, not sure how but you definitely helped, thanks.